# MQTT - listen to ping, disconnect and connect events

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have "server side" mqtt client which I use to monitor and manage remote mqtt clients. I would like to extend this server module to keep tabs on the connectivity of the remote clients.

During normal operation, the remote clients regularly PING the broker, as per the broker logs:

```
1532924170: Received PINGREQ from c51
1532924170: Sending PINGRESP to c51
```

and when a disconnection occurs, the broker logs show this too:

```
1532924976: Client c51 has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1532924976: Socket error on client c51, disconnecting.
```

as well as the subsequent re-connection:

```
1532924978: New client connected from X.X.X.X as c51 (c1, k30).
1532924978: Sending CONNACK to c51 (0, 0)
```

I would like to monitor these 3 events from the mqtt-client held by the server module. Is this possible? If not, what alternative approach to "health" monitoring can you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not read these from a connected client.

The only pure MQTT approach is to make use of the Last Will and Testament (LWT) feature. You have the client set up a LWT publish a retained message to a client specific topic that marks it as offline. Then as the client connects it should publish a retained message to show you are online. If you disconnect cleanly (not triggered by keep alive time out you should manually publish the LWT message as the last thing before disconnecting).

It's also worth pointing out that ping messages only get sent if no other messages have been sent between the client and the broker in the keep alive period.

Comment: thanks @hardillb - i'm struggling to get my LWT published by mosquitto though - hence the other approach.

Comment: Unless you want to go down the route of building your own broker (with something like mosca) then LWT is your only option (and it will cross broker as it's part of the spec)

Comment: @pstanton I've just remembered technically you can redirect all mosquitto log messages to a `$SYS/broker/log/...` topic so you can consume them in a remote client, but the LWT option is still the best way forward.

Comment: agree @hardillb - i've solved my issue with LWT now so have implemented your approach.

Comment: Best Practices – When should you use LWT? https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament